# Is it necessary to scale/process regression targets after PCA?

Tags: regression, pca

I have a regression problem where the dimensionality of my targets is too large (40D) so I use PCA to reduce the dimensionality to 15 dimensions. I don't do any more processing to my targets before training, but is it necessary or does it make sense to process the post-PCA targets further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to standardize, I would recommend standardizing BEFORE extracting principal components. This can keep scaling differences from weighing some predictors too heavily. At the same time, standardizing may remove important characteristics from the data. It's up to you, but either way, I would do this as a preprocessing step.